# Preventing some templates to be defined

Tags: c++

I am designing a Dynamic class that can store any kind of value. It is defined as:

```
class Dynamic {
 private:
  Type type_;
  std::uint64_t data_;

 public:
  Dynamic();
  ... 
}
```

where Type is an enum that contains ids of all the types I can store in the Dynamic object : `unsigned char`, `signed char`, `char`, ..., `unsigned short`, `short`, `std::size_t`, `std::ptrdiff_t`, `float`, `double`, `std::vector<unsigned char>`, ..., `std::vector<double>`, etc. Think about 200 types.

I would like to construct the Dynamic object very easily. If the type T is supported, the following code should work.

```
void f(const T& x) {
  il::Dynamic d = x;
  ...
}
```

It could be implemented very easily with the following constructor:

```
template <typename T>
Dynamic(const T& x) {
  ...
}
```

except that I have the following problem. On 64-bit platforms

```
const il::Dynamic d0 = 1'000'000'000;
```

would create an Dynamic containing an int, and

```
const il::Dynamic d1 = 10'000'000'000;
```

would create something else (don't even want to know if it is a long, or a long long). I don't want that, and the only integer type I want to use above 32 bits is a signed integer of the same size as `std::size_t` which is `std::ptrdiff_t`. As a consequence, I want to prevent the constructor to work with the following types : `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`, except one which is `std::ptrdiff_t`. How could I do such as thing?

Comment: Aside from the question itself, is there any reason you don't use `std::any` or `std::variant`?

Comment: Search "ad hoc polymorphism." If something like that is really desirable, which it almost never is, there are better ways. Maybe virtual inheritance, or RTTI, or std::any, or std::variant, or one of the other things I am not thinking of at the moment.

Comment: @lisyarus: This is part of a library, and most of my clients compile without RTTI. Moreover, I want the best performance, and rolling out your own implementation allows you many tricks such as having a `Dynamic` types of 64 bits ans storing in place types such as integers and doubles.

Comment: @InsideLoop Then, `std::variant` should suit you: it doesn't use RTTI, and takes up the minimum required amount of space, while being much more type-safe.

Comment: @lisyarus: There are more than 100 types, so the `std::variant` would have a lot of template parameters. But that could be ok. Except that in the end, I want my Dynamic object to use only 8 bytes. The reason for that is this `Dynamic` type is usually stored as the value of an hash table where the key is a string that takes 24 bytes. That way, I can put 2 (key, value) pairs in one cacheline which makes think really fast. And I am limited to `C++11`.

Answer (score 2):

Specialize it and mark it as `delete` explicitly:

```
Dynamic(int) = delete;
Dynamic(unsigned int) = delete;
Dynamic(long) = delete;
Dynamic(unsigned long) = delete;
...
```

Repeat this for all types you don't want. Then when you attempt to call it you get a compile error.

If you want the reverse thing, i.e. allow the constructor for some types while blocking everything else, you can also do the reverse:

```
template <typename T>
Dynamic(const T& x) = delete;

Dynamic(char x) { /* Your code */ };
Dynamic(short x) { /* Your code */ };
Dynamic(std::size_t x) { /* Your code */ };
...
```

In this way only the types that you explicitly implemented will be allowed, as all other types will be matched by the template and rejected (with a compile error).

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is only half solved. Among `int`, `long` and `long long`, I want to delete all but `std::ptrdiff_t` which I believe could be `long` or `long long` depending upon the platform (even on 64-bit CPUs). For the time being, I use your second solution that works but is really painful (I have hundreds of types).

Answer (score 2):

You might `delete` the unwanted methods (via overloads):

```
class Dynamic {
public:
    template <typename T>
    Dynamic(const T& x) {
        // Your code...
    }

    Dynamic(int) = delete;
    Dynamic(unsigned int) = delete;
    Dynamic(long) = delete;
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::enable_if` to restrict the use of a template function.

In the following code, `is_allowed` by default allows a type to be used in your constructor. Then you specialize `is_allowed` for those types you don't want to make `is_allowed` inherit from `std::false_type`, thus prevent them from being used in your constructor.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct is_allowed : std::true_type {};

template<>
struct is_allowed<int> : std::false_type {};

template<>
struct is_allowed<unsigned int> : std::false_type {};

/* ... */

class Dynamic {
public:
    template<class T,
        std::enable_if_t<is_allowed<T>::value, bool> = true>
    Dynamic(const T& x) { /* ... */ }
};
```

**UPDATE:**

Since OP says the size of `std::ptrdiff_t` is not known. So all types that should be removed cannot be listed manually. I assume from OP's info that the condition to accept a type is

`!std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_same_v<T, std::ptrdiff_t>`

For other conditions, the solution is similar. Here is the code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct is_allowed {
    constexpr static bool value = !std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_same_v<T, std::ptrdiff_t>;
};

class Dynamic {
public:
    template<class T,
        std::enable_if_t<is_allowed<T>::value, bool> = true>
    Dynamic(const T& x) { /* ... */ }
};
```

This works for C++17. It's also ok for C++11/C++14, just replace that `_v` by `::value` and `_t` by `::type` respectively.

Comment: `std::is_base_of_v<std::true_type, is_allowed<T>>` can be replaced by `is_allowed<T>::value` (and you can even add `_v` version if you want).

Comment: Prefer `std::enable_if_t<cond, bool> = false` over `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>`. see [default-template-argument-when-using-stdenable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305222/default-template-argument-when-using-stdenable-if-as-templ-param-why-ok-wit).

Comment: @Jarod42 Nice point in that answer. But maybe using `std::enable_if_t<cond, bool> = true` "looks" more nature.

Comment: or `std::enable_if_t<cond, void*> = nullptr`. You got my point.