# Function SFINAE overload works only with non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, sfinae

I was implementing a casting function and needed different implementations for fundamental types and for containers (for example simplicity let's say that `std::is_compound` is enough). I noticed that it works if my second template argument is not a type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_compound<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
T cast() {
    T result{};
    std::cout << "compound impl" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
T cast() {
    T result{};
    std::cout << "fundamental impl" << std::endl;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << cast<std::vector<int> >().size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << cast<float>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the compiler complains that I have

> error: redefinition of 'template<class T, class V> T cast()'

if I use this approach:

```
template<class T, class V = typename std::enable_if<std::is_compound<T>::value>::type >
T cast() {
    T result{};
    std::cout << "compound impl" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
template<class T, class V = typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type >
T cast() {
    T result{};
    std::cout << "fundamental impl" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/j9TPbb)

Why the code compiles for non-type template argument (`void*` in this case) and fails for type template argument?

Comment: Misread the question, duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter

Comment: @NathanOliver thx, I left it commented and forgot to uncomment

Comment: Hmm, I see that in the linked question the accepted answer mentions "(...) default template arguments are not considered (...) return type (again see 14.5.6.1/4). Since this expression is part of signature". But if the default args are not considered, then why does it work in my first example? And I thought that return type is actually not in the function signature, right?

Comment: Related to [default-template-argument-when-using-stdenable-if-as-templ-param-why-ok-wit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305222/default-template-argument-when-using-stdenable-if-as-templ-param-why-ok-wit)

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks, [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305294/4165552) the question