# enable_if fails without decltype in return type

Tags: c++, sfinae, enable-if

I have 3 overloads of a function each guarded by `enable_if`

```
struct thing{
    typedef int data_type;
    
    template <typename T, int N = 0, typename = typename std::enable_if<N == 0 &&  std::is_same<T, data_type>::value>::type>
    data_type data() { return 1; }
    template <typename T, int N = 0, typename = typename std::enable_if<N == 0 && !std::is_same<T, data_type>::value>::type>
    auto data() { return 0; }
    template <typename T, int N, typename = typename std::enable_if<N != 0>::type>
    auto data() { return -1; }
};
```

The above code fails to compile with error

```
test.cpp:12:10: error: ‘template<class T, int N, class> auto thing::data()’ cannot be overloaded with ‘template<class T, int N, class> auto thing::data()’
   12 |     auto data() { return -1; }
      |          ^~~~
test.cpp:10:10: note: previous declaration ‘template<class T, int N, class> auto thing::data()’
   10 |     auto data() { return 0; }
```

Each of these functions can be distinguished from each other with the third template argument. What is the reason behind SFINAE failure ?

On the other hand the following works

```
template <typename T, int N = 0, typename = typename std::enable_if<N == 0 && !std::is_same<T, data_type>::value>::type>
auto data() { return 0; }
template <typename T, int N, typename = typename std::enable_if<N != 0>::type>
decltype(auto) data() { return -1; }
```

and returns correct results

```
thing t;
std::cout << "t.data<int>(): "       << t.data<int>() << std::endl;       //  1
std::cout << "t.data<double>(): "    << t.data<double>() << std::endl;    //  0
std::cout << "t.data<int, 1>(): "    << t.data<int, 1>() << std::endl;    // -1
std::cout << "t.data<double, 1>(): " << t.data<double, 1>() << std::endl; // -1
```

Why and how `decltype` helps in this situation ?

Comment: See [default-template-argument-when-using-stdenable-if-as-templ-param-why-ok-wit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305222/default-template-argument-when-using-stdenable-if-as-templ-param-why-ok-wit/38305320#38305320)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not overloads; they are redeclarations (and redefinitions) of the same function template:

```
template<class, int, class> auto data();
```

Default template parameters do not make a different function template; nor does a different deduced return type, however swapping `auto` for `decltype(auto)` does make a different function template.

If suitable, the best solution would be [to use concepts](https://godbolt.org/z/3cdjfe), since a different template-constraint makes for a different function template:

```
template <typename T, int N = 0>
data_type data() requires (N == 0 &&  std::is_same_v<T, data_type>) { return 1; }
template <typename T, int N = 0>
auto data() requires (N == 0 && !std::is_same_v<T, data_type>) { return 0; }
template <typename T, int N>
auto data() requires (N != 0) { return -1; }
```

Otherwise, you could [add more dummy template arguments](https://godbolt.org/z/za5M7o):

```
template <typename T, int N = 0, typename = typename std::enable_if<N == 0 && !std::is_same<T, data_type>::value>::type>
auto data() { return 0; }
template <typename T, int N, int = 0, typename = typename std::enable_if<N != 0>::type>
auto data() { return -1; } // ^^^^^^ add dummy template parameter
```

Answer (score 3):

Default (template) argument is not part of signature,

It should be

```
struct thing{
    typedef int data_type;
    
    template <typename T, int N = 0, typename std::enable_if<N == 0 &&  std::is_same<T, data_type>::value, int>::type = 0>
    data_type data() { return 1; }
    template <typename T, int N = 0, typename std::enable_if<N == 0 && !std::is_same<T, data_type>::value, int>::type = 0>
    auto data() { return 0; }
    template <typename T, int N, typename std::enable_if<N != 0, int>::type = 0>
    auto data() { return -1; }
};
```