# A proper way to disable a class constructor based on a trait of that class

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I would like to SFINAE-disable a class template constructor - but the catch is that an enable-disable condition is a trait of that class. Particularly, I would like to enable that constructor only if a specific class method, matching constructor's template arguments, exists in that class.

A simplified example:

```
struct S
{
    std::size_t n = 0;
    void set_value(int i) { n = i; }
    void set_value(const std::string & s) { n = s.size(); }
    template <class T, class = decltype(std::declval<S>().set_value(std::declval<T>()))>
    S(T && x)
    {
        set_value(std::forward<T>(x));
    }
};
```

That solution works in GCC and, allegedly, in MSVC, but does not work in Clang. And in my opinion Clang is in the right here, because inside a class definition class isn't yet defined, so `std::declval<S>()` should not work here.

So my idea was to move that constructor definition out of class definition:

```
struct S
{
    std::size_t n = 0;
    void set_value(int i) { n = i; }
    void set_value(const std::string & s) { n = s.size(); }
    template <class T, class>
    S(T &&);
};

template <class T, class = decltype(std::declval<S>().set_value(std::declval<T>()))>
S::S(T && x)
{
    set_value(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

But that doesn't work in GCC and MSVC. That solution also looks somewhat fishy, because I first declare that constructor unconditionally and only later introduce SFINAE.

My question is - is it possible at all to solve that task in C++11/14/17? A specific task is that a class should have a constructor only if it also have a matching setter method. Obviously, one can manually define a non-template constructor for every setter method overload, but that tedious and hard to maintain.

But I'm also interested in more general task - SFINAE-enabling a constructor or other class method by a trait of that class (requiring a complete class definition).

Also, which compiler is more right in my example - GCC/MSVC or Clang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can introduce another template parameter with default value `S`, and use it for SFINAE. E.g.

```
template <class T, class X = S, class = decltype(std::declval<X>().set_value(std::declval<T>()))>
S(T && x)
{
    set_value(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/It6jaVuDUQgzqtIU)

Comment: IIRC, default template arguments are not considered for SFINAE. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DanielLangr The gotcha for default template arguments and SFINAE is that we may not provide two overloads which differ only in their default template arguments; SFINAE would, in theory, work for this but the program would be ill-formed as default template arguments are not part of function template's signature.

Comment: @dfrib Thanks for the clarification, it makes sense.

Comment: @DanielLangr [Related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305222/default-template-argument-when-using-stdenable-if-as-templ-param-why-ok-wit).

Answer (score 1):

For your question about which compiler is right, this is [CWG1836](http://wg21.link/CWG1836)

The problem is not `std::declval`: You can use `std::declval<S>` with incomplete `S`, since it returns a `S&&`. The issue is when you use `std::declval<S>().set_value`, since `S` is not complete at that moment.

However, there is an explicit exception:

> the class type shall be complete unless the class member access appears in the definition of that class.

And the class member access *does* appear in the definition of `S`.

So gcc and msvc are right to allow it.

---

It seems like clang does not apply the resolution of CWG1836. In that case, it sees that `std::declval<S>()` does not have a dependent type, so it can immediately evaluate the member access `std::declval<S>().set_value` (and fails to do so).

To appease clang, you can make it a dependent type. For example, since you are already in a template, you can make it dependent on what `T` is:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename...>
struct dependent_type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T, typename... Dependence>
using dependent_type_identity_t = typename dependent_type_identity<T, Dependence...>::type;

struct S
{
    std::size_t n = 0;
    void set_value(int i) { n = i; }
    void set_value(const std::string & s) { n = s.size(); }
    template <class T, class = decltype(std::declval<dependent_type_identity_t<S, T>>().set_value(std::declval<T>()))>
    S(T && x)
    {
        set_value(std::forward<T>(x));
    }
};
```

Or do what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65715739/5754656) does, and make it dependent on another template argument which defaults to `S` (it is still a dependent type, even if there is no way to change what it is set to)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Nice to know that it was properly addressed in the standard. Although, the solution with additional template argument is simpler, so I'll mark that as accepted.